# Install wxPython on Mac os Mavericks

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, osx-mavericks

I am on a Macbook Air, running Mavericks. Today I downloaded wxPython via their website, however, when I click on the install package I get:

```
wxPython3.0-osx-cocoa-py2.7.pkg” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should eject the disk image.
```

Anyone have any ideas to get around this, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried re-downloading it to make sure you didn't just get a corrupted download?

Comment: yup, same error, and a prompt to eject the disk.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to [#14523](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/14523), the problem is that the package is not signed (and it's an old-style package, which isn't fully supported anymore, which is why you get the wrong error message, and the usual workaround of context-clicking Open doesn't work).

There are two workarounds:

First, you can [turn off Gatekeeper](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5290?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) (in System Preferences, Security & Privacy, General, select the "Allow apps downloads from: … Anywhere" radio button), install wxPython, then turn Gatekeeper back on.

Alternatively, you can install from the command line:

```
sudo installer -pkg /path/to/wxPython.pkg -target /
```

Comment: Yes, I temporarily turned off gatekeeper and installed wxPython. Thanks!

Comment: The 2nd option approach gave me the error `installer[50506:1308089] Package /Volumes/wxPython3.0-osx-3.0.2.0-cocoa-py2.7/wxPython3.0-osx-cocoa-py2.7.pkg uses a deprecated pre-10.2 format (or uses a newer format but is invalid).
installer: The install failed (The Installer could not install the software because there was no software found to install.)`

Answer (score 5):

As with so many other packages, install `wxpython` with brew:

`brew install wxpython`

I hit this problem with El Capitan (10.11.2) and tried some of the workarounds mentioned elsewhere (install via command-line, allow installation of unsigned apps, etc) with no luck.  Use brew!

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer didn't work for me on macOS Sierra.

I had to manually repackage the the original package as described here:
https://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/17203#comment:8

Comment: Thanks - needed to use 2.8 and of course that's the only way

Answer (score -1):

Use brew* to install wxmac using the following command.

brew install --python wxmac --devel

once you install the wxmac create a symbolic link between the installed wx to the python library.

sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/wxmac/2.9.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/wx

I Hope it will be helpful for future installers.

*if you do not have Brew installed prior, install it using the following command: ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"

Comment: I just tried this.  (wx was in a different spot, but I changed the link.)  When I try to import wx, though, it says, "No module named wx".