# Installation wxpython fails on OSX10.11 despite change to security settings and using the command line install

Tags: macos, wxpython, installation

I'm trying to install wxPython 3.0.2 for Cocoa on OSX 10.11. And I find some link [Install wxPython on Mac os Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223717/install-wxpython-on-mac-os-mavericks) and [wxPython OSX binaries won't install on MacOS 10.8 Mountain Lion - need signing](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/14523)

I have adjusted my GateKeeper settings so that installer will launch despite the missing signature. 
However, installation then fails saying "The Installer could not install the software because there was no software found to install.)".

I have tried using the command line install, but it quits with the same error message:
sudo installer -pkg /Volumes/wxPython3.0-osx-3.0.2.0-cocoa-py2.7/wxPython3.0-osx-cocoa-py2.7.pkg/ -target /

Password:

installer: Package name is wxPython3.0-osx-cocoa-py2.7

installer: Installing at base path /

2015-10-18 15:29:57.977 installer[24690:510968] Package /Volumes/wxPython3.0-osx-3.0.2.0-cocoa-py2.7/wxPython3.0-osx-cocoa-py2.7.pkg uses a deprecated pre-10.2 format (or uses a newer format but is invalid).

installer: The install failed (The Installer could not install the software because there was no software found to install.)

I have found that I use the default python that comes preinstalled on OSX. Whether this will affect.

Please advise how to install wxPython on OSX 10.11.

Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same problem. I am also using OSX 10.11 but I am using a manually installed copy of Python 2.7.9, not the system bundled copy of Python.

Answer (score 3):

This question can be solved by 3 steps with building the wxpython.

Firstly, download the source code from github. It is the
[wxpython](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython) and
[wxwidgets(this version is latest)](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/tree/WX_3_0_BRANCH)

Secondly，read the build-wxpython.py file of the sourcecode. we find that there must be wxpython and wxwidgets, and this two files must be put in the same root directory. And the wxwidgets file name is the "wxWidgets".

Thirdly,compile those in terminal with correct parameter.

`cd wxPython-src-3.0.0.0/wxPython
python2.6 build-wxpython.py --build_dir=../bld --osx_cocoa`

Comment: I did exactly the same thing, however, at step 3, while `python2.6 build-wxpython.py --build_dir=../bld --osx_cocoa` execute, it generates many warnings > expression with side effects will be evaluated despite being used as an operand to 'typeid' [-Wpotentially-evaluated-expression]
    WX_DECLARE_ANY_VALUE_TYPE(wxAnyValueTypeImplVariantData)

Comment: This solution allowed me to build wxPython successfully from source but I couldn't use `import wx` in a Python file until I added `/path/to/wxPython/` to my `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. Now everything seems to be working properly.